# Should we have a community ad for the resources list on Main?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, advertising

On the Main site [we have a list of worldbuilding resources](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/143606/is-there-a-list-of-worldbuilding-resources) which aims to improve the quality of questions asked on the Main site. The idea is that general questions about worldbuilding, which would normally be closed anyway for being unclear or off-topic, get answered. Additionally, it may help a user to narrow down their question or to recognise that their question would not be suitable for the Main worldbuilding site. If you are interested in reading more about it, there is a [Meta discussion](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/should-we-have-a-resource-list-on-main) about if we should have the list on Main.

My question is if there should be a community ad which links to this list of resources.

Being a relatively new user to this site, only 57 days at the time of writing, i am unsure if it would be appropriate to have an ad that links to a question on the Main site. The closest analogy would be the Sandbox which has an ad on Main that links to a ‘question’ on the Meta site. I feel that the list of resources is akin to the Sandbox in that both are aimed at, primarily, new users to improve the general quality of questions asked on the Main site. There is also a community ad to the SFF.SE site with the words “Get Inspired” who’s purpose seems to inspire WB.SE users to write interesting questions, a similar but not quite the same idea.

I feel the list of resources would greatly benefit from having a community ad, it would allow for new users to easily see there is somewhere they can go to get their general questions answered and improve the quality of future questions.

However, i would like to hear the thoughts and opinions of users who are more experienced than i.

Answer (score 3):

I think an **advert would be very useful**. Yet should not be the only thing. An additional link to the resources question from places such as the *help-section* and the *create question page* would be very useful as well.

---

The problematic thing I see is the question itself though, it needs moderation and guidelines on how the list should be set up. At the point of writing this answer, the list is mostly links to the same website over and over - this is not useful at all but rather bad, as it drowns any other sites/guides.

---

So my conclusion: An ad would be a good next step, but **before the ad** we need a clean idea of how the list is to be maintained and expanded.

Comment: A fair point, i suppose then the real question here is how we go about creating said guidelines.