# Where do I go if I'm just fishing for ideas?

Tags: discussion

I have a question that I know is too broad with no definitive answer, and as I understand Worldbuilding Stack Exchange, this is considered just fishing for ideas. Does anyone know of a place I *can* ask this without issue?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I usually like to recommend [our site chat room, the Factory Floor](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/the-factory-floor), for people looking to toss around ideas and grab some inspiration. We have a pretty active group of regulars who often tend toward inane topics of discussion but will gladly help someone who's looking for a more informal environment of this sort. Peak activity is usually 12:00 UTC - 18:00 UTC, but there might be people hanging around at odd hours.

I don't want to suggest that you go to chat every time you want to ask a question that wouldn't fit on the main site for various reasons, but every once in a while, it can be a great resource, as well as a nice chance to interact closely with members of the community.

Comment: ITS A TRAP!  But seriously this is good advice.  I do like to provide the standard *"it gets weird in there"* warning to newcomers. :D

Comment: Also, if you can only visit during off peak hours because of timezones, you can still ask a question, and someone will likely respond. So if the room is quiet, just ask the question and give some details.

Comment: The best thing about this answer is that participating in [chat] helps you learn how to craft fishing-for-ideas questions that are suitable for the site.  Don't just listen to the list of ideas, listen to the clarifying questions they ask.  You'll discover that most of the issue is *how* you present an idea with appropriate restrictions and expectations.

Answer (score 4):

[The Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7183/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) could a good place to go if you need help making an answer more specific. User JBH manages it mostly but there's a handful of other users who will help you as well. It's always worth trying your question out on there to see how it can be improved, in your case it may be possible to break it down into several different questions.

Beyond that we have our [List of Resources](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/143606/is-there-a-list-of-worldbuilding-resources) on the Main site. This is simply a bunch of links to various websites focused around Worldbuilding. Whilst you can’t ask questions on these sites, you may find some answers to your question. The list itself is categorised so you should be able to find something that might help. It is also being updated with new links so check back now and again. Even if they don’t answer your question, they’re still worth a look at as they may be able to help you narrow it down, making it a better fit to ask on the Main site.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it in a Q&A answer format, Quora will take any and all kinds of questions.

Seriously. I often see things like "How would 5 marines with current equipment available fare against a roman legion" - which, if asked here, I would gladly downvote and vote to close in two breaths.

That's because Quora does not care as much about solving problems as SE users do. They care more about having a huge amount of questions answered.

So you can go there, ask who would win in a fight between a bicycle and an octopus, and you will probably get answers. Don't expect them to be good answers, or to give you any useful ideas though.

There is also Yahoo! Answers, but as far as Q&A sites go that one is just slightly better than 4Chan. They are both cesspools where reason goes to die.

Comment: The vulgar "Q" and "R" words!  Aaaah!  Give me the Knights who say Nee!  every time!

Comment: @JBH “We want... a shrubbery! One that looks nice, and not too expensive [...] Then, you must cut down the largest tree in the forest wiiiith a herring!”

Comment: Are the bicycle and octopus fighting on land or underwater?

Comment: @Willk wait... is the octopus fighting *with* the bicycle or *against* the bicycle?