# Is background lore considered worldbuilding or storytelling?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I'm hoping to ask a question related to a funny narrator anecdote similar to what you find in Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy, though with some interaction with the main character. However, I'm not entirely sure if anecdotes like that are considered worldbuilding or storytelling. In case it's relevant, the anecdote is about a chef with germophobia who does not want to have any utensils or cooking wear or surfaces to contact the food he's preparing, not even when the guests are eating it, and who does everything with lasers for cutting and magnets for manipulating the food. The question I wanted to ask is what cooking techniques he wouldn't be able to use (although if this is too broad, let me know and I'll jump by in chat or the sandbox to see if I can get something with a narrower scope put together). Is this considered worldbuilding with regards to the scope of the site?

Comment: We have a sandbox for this, so that meta doesn't get clogged with "is this question in scope?"

Comment: Nzall it may not be a good fit for the main site but if you jump in our [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/the-factory-floor) people are generally happy to discuss stuff like this.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for clarifying before opening a question. You may also use [the Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7183/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) to see whether a question is fit for the site, and get help on how to improve it.

As it stands, there is not much about the building of a world there - you wish to discuss [what a character would do](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6992/21222), not how a world would work. That is story based.

There is a stack that is scoped towards writing stories. However, writing.SE helps users on questions related to *how to write*, never *what to write*.

It seems to me that you wish to refine a joke. While I collect comedy sci-fi and I would love to help, ultimately you are seeking for a creative solution for a scene. I do not think there is a site at Stack Exchange that can be of much help, but I do wish you think of something clever that you end up liking for your novel.