# Is this question really off-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, close-reasons, vote-to-close

I don't know much about the tags or rules in Meta, since I usually just briefly lurk, so I'd appreciate it if someone can fix the tags to be more appropriate and I apologise if I've broken any rules here.

I'm asking about my question [is there other possible fuel for fire other than common oil/fuel?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/157308/is-there-other-possible-fuel-for-fire-other-than-common-oil-fuel), as it was closed as off-topic and there was no explanation whatsoever of why it was considered off-topic in the comments, so maybe I'm missing something?

Since my question basically asks about any unique, exotic or uncommon fuels for lighting fires, with the criteria mentioned in the question

About the duel inspection, it is to explain what it is, when it happens, and how it works. And as for the duel itself, it is to explain what the fire alternative is used for so I can get a clearer answer.

If it's considered story-based, I personally don't see it that way, so I'm kinda confused. Usually, before a question gets closed, someone will mention the flaw in the comments.

So is my question really not about worldbuilding?

Comment: I've tidied up your English for you. No need to apologise, I'm sure you speak English much better than I speak your native language, and someone will always come along and make any necessary grammar fixes.

Comment: The question asks if anybody knows *"any **other** good material or chemical that can make a fire wall"* without even bothering to first list the materials (physical or metaphysical) which are considered "common" fuels in the hypothetical village / town / city / country / world. "Other" than what? [Blau gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blau_gas)?

Comment: @AlexP but i have put the list in the description, what i mean with common fuel in the text there so am i miss something? here copy paste of it.  "outside of common oil/gas (such as alcohol,gasoline, and plant/animals fat/oil) and dry/wood plant (including coal/peat,potato,paper,or any plantbase) which is boring and easy to be recognise by common people, and oil/gas smell."

Comment: including jet fuel,greek fire,dead animal/carcass, and poop

Answer (score -2):

I cast the first vote. I could not see how you could build a fictional world with that.

World building is about creating a world. Listing materials that do something in the real world creates a setting, not a world.

For example, I might come here and ask about how do we measure the strength of an acid so I know which substances to use on a scene, or what kinds of wood make for the best bows so that I can place a character in a forest of that material. It creates setting, but not a world. If you are writing a novel, or a videogame, or if you are making a tabletop-RPG game... what you need is some research, fact-checking, and maybe some help with writing. But trust me, in these situations, if you wish to science out things you just make them boring for the readers/players.

Still, I don't see how you can build a world with those.

As a very general guideline, if you need help with [a situation](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6992/21222) (specially when [it is about a small set of characters](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6140/21222)), it tends to not be on topic.

I encourage you to use the [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7183/sandbox-for-proposed-questions), where you can refine questions if you are unsure about them being on-topic.

Comment: next time can you at last provide reason in the comment beforehand, the VTC occur at night and your reply happen in the middle of the night in my place and iam sleepy. well boring is subjective after all and i personally dont care about what other consider as boring but apreciate nonetheless. i dont know much about the difference between "setting" and "worldbuilding" so i wont argue much about it despite i believe i see similar question like this without getting VTC but no proof though as i dont know the difference to point it out.

Comment: i know this is old already but after reading some answer here that mention the purpose of WB, seems like settings is part of it, WB.SE's mission is: Worldbuilding Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for writers, artists and others using science, geography and culture to construct imaginary worlds and settings.