# How do I delete a question once it has answers?

Tags: discussion, support

So, I recently asked a [question on Meta](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7645/what-to-do-if-your-question-answer-is-downvoted-out-of-bias) about what I should do about one of my answers that was being downvoted out of bias (I am a ID proponent, and apparently SE is highly Evolutionist). Anyway, this question turned into a bunch of people saying that I am wrong for being a Creationist.

When I went to delete the question, I was alerted that I cannot delete it, since people had "answered" it, and it is "unfair" that the "work" they put into it should be deleted.

How do I delete it anyway?

Comment: I don't mean to be blunt, but there isn't a way for you to delete it, for the reasons given. It's a valuable discussion, and as far as I can see, only certain comments talk about creationism at all; the answers address your core concern.

Comment: The error message you got and HDE’s comment are correct: you can’t delete your question, because it would unilaterally rob people of the effort they put into answering it.

Comment: To be clear we're talking about a question you asked on Meta? AFIAK there is no consequence for a question being downvoted on meta*. *With the exception of spamming meta with poor questions.

Comment: @sphennings : It is not about loss of reputation, it is with the acute off-topicness.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot for the reasons listed. Doesn't matter if it is the main site or meta. It would have to be extraordinarily problematic for a moderator to step in and delete it.

I suppose you could run for moderator if we ever have another election, and then, if you win, you could delete it.

Comment: Nope to the last sentence. Moderators are not above the rules. Answered questions do not get deleted, that's a rule.

Comment: @ldutch but it is a power you have, right? So if thescribe is the last moderator remaining...?