# How can I draw attention to a Sandbox item (proposed question posted as an answer)?

Tags: discussion, sandbox

It is my very first encounter with the [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7183/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) which is a great idea especially for newbies. However I have noticed that I have received very little feedback for [my item](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7183/sandbox-for-proposed-questions/8046#8046) and I am wondering about what to do next.

For actual questions we have bounties to draw attention, but those cannot be used for an answer.

Or maybe I should go ahead and ask it on the main site?

Comment: Posting a meta question is sure to draw some attention. I like (actually love) your question in the sandbox - but since it is something readily applicable in the real world and sadly due to politics I don't know how it would be accepted in the main site; however, I say give it a go. You have my upvote, and even if it doesn't go well, you're more likely to get more positive reputation than negative.

Comment: @Renan Thanks for your suggestion. I have already posted the question and it received a couple of great answers.

Comment: Other than following your link to it, I don't even know where the sandbox is, or how to use it. I clicked on your link, it led me to a question, then it vanished.