# Sandbox for proposed Questions

Tags: discussion, questions, sandbox

***The Sandbox works best if you sort posts by "active" (click [here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9981/40609?answertab=active) to do so).***

---

## Welcome to the Sandbox!

This ["Sandbox"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(software_development)) is a place where Worldbuilding.SE users can get feedback on prospective questions they wish to [post](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions). This is useful, because new and experienced users can have trouble writing a clear and fully specified question.

- There is a much better chance of your question being well received if you post it in the Sandbox first.

*If you're here to help mentor Sandbox questions (**THANK YOU!**), jump to the "Helping in the Sandbox" section.  If this sandbox has grown too full, jump to the "Maintenance" section.*

- **Please don't vote on any of the proposed questions in the Sandbox**. Votes don't mean anything here and you could inadvertently bias others who might help, or worse, make a new person feel like their question writing skills are hopeless. Or worse yet, much better than they are. If you think a question is good, leave a note of encouragement and a helpful tip. If you think a question is bad, leave a note of encouragement and offer your help to make it better!

---

## Posting to the Sandbox

**Please take the time to read through the [Help Center > Asking](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/asking) pages.** We know it's a lot to read, but those pages contain the rules our mentors are using to judge your proposed question.  If you have not taken the time to read through them, we ask that you do.  It would also be beneficial to read through our Meta posts about [high concept questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868), [open-ended questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6654), and what "[primarily opinion-based](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6436#6437)" means on a creative site like Worldbuilding.SE.

**To post a question to the Sandbox:**
Post an answer to this post with the content of your proposed question. You can create as many answers as you have proposed questions, but it is recommended that you only work on one question at a time. The content of the post should be as close as possible to the format you would use when asking on the main site. If you would like, you may add a section at the bottom explaining what parts of the proposed question you are most worried about (See the [Sandbox FAQ](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/640/2685) for more information on suggested syntax).

**Once you have posted your proposed question,** users will be able to comment on it with feedback. You can then respond to their feedback with comments of your own, or make edits to your post to attempt to address their feedback (after editing, be sure to notify the user via a comment of your own, use *[@username](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36026)* in your comment to make this happen). The feedback/edit cycle can go on for as long as needed until either you are confident that your question is ready to be asked on the main site, or you've decided the question just won't work.

- Please be patient.  While most sandbox reviews can be completed in a couple of days, some questions may require a week or more for review.

**Finally, please ignore votes.** We've asked mentors to not vote for Sandbox questions because questions change here too frequently.  Nevertheless, those index fingers hovering over left mouse buttons are trained to vote, so votes occasionally appear.  Please completely ignore votes that happen to appear for your proposed question.

### When your question is ready

1. [Post it to the main site](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).
2. Add a link to your main-site post to the bottom of the "Graduated Questions" list.  The list is the accepted answer to this post.
3. Edit your Sandbox post so that it only contains the title and a link to the main-site post.  *Delete everything else.*
4. ***Delete all of your comments.***
5. Finally, delete your Sandbox post.  Users with enough rep can still see the post, but it will be moved automatically to the bottom of the answer list, making this Sandbox easier to use.

### If you abandon your question

Occasionally a Sandbox question is abandoned.  While crafting the question, you may discover the answer.  Or you may realize that the question's basic premise can't be expressed within the [rules of Worldbuilding.SE](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8491/40609).  You may also simply forget that you have a question in the Sandbox.  If you decide to abandon the question:

1. Edit your Sandbox post so that it only contains the title and a notice (e.g., "Abandoned question.").  *Delete everything else.*
2. ***Delete all of your comments.***
3. Finally, delete your Sandbox post.  Users with enough rep can still see the post, but it will be moved automatically to the bottom of the answer list, making this Sandbox easier to use.

**Please be aware** that questions without activity (edits to your question or comments left by you) for more than one month may be judged abandoned and removed.  We'll leave a comment or two to get your attention, but eventually, forgotten questions will be cleaned up and deleted.

---

## Helping in the Sandbox

We are sincerely grateful for the many users who help mentor questions and new users here in the Sandbox.  Sharing your experience adds considerably to the quality and enjoyment of the site.  We invite you to help us by adhering to the following policies.

**Keep the Sandbox clean.** In order to [keep the Sandbox clean](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2244/sandbox-cleanup) users are encouraged to [look out for questions that have not seen any activity in some time](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4912/28789).

1. If you notice the OP has not edited his/her proposed question or left a comment in 2 or more weeks, please tap the OP on the shoulder with a comment (e.g., "Are you still working on this question?  This draft might be deleted if there is no further activity.")
2. If you notice the OP has not edited his/her proposed question or left a comment in more than a month, please flag the question for moderator attention (e.g., "This Sandbox question has been inactive for a month.").  ***Please do not take it upon yourself to delete the OP's question.***

**Delete your comments when they no longer apply.** Please make it easy for others to see which comments are still relevant to the discussion by removing your obsolete comments. In addition you can ask a mod to [purge comments under graduated posts or move them to chat under abandoned posts](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6231/28789) to make it easier for users that can see deleted posts to use the Sandbox.

**Please do not vote on proposed questions.** Questions in the Sandbox frequently change (it's why they're here) — and the moment they change your vote may no longer reflect your beliefs.  It's unreasonable to expect mentors to constantly watch Sandbox questions and there is no automatic way (indeed, there's no way at all…) to notify voters when a question is edited.  It is better to use comments.  If you feel the question should be downvoted, explain the problem in a comment.  If you feel the question is ready for the main site, say so in a comment.  The dates on the comments allow other people to judge the relevance of your statements.

**Please do not answer questions here.** We know it's tempting, but answering the question in a comment will clog the comments and may not even be relevant to the final form of the question. If you have an answer for the proposed question, simply wait for it to be posted to the main site, and answer it there.

**Please do not edit a proposed question** unless you have the OP's permission to do so.  The purpose of the Sandbox is two-fold: (a) to perfect a question and (b) to help users learn to craft good questions.  If you jump in and fix a question you've subverted (b).  Whenever possible, let the OP edit their proposed question.  *Exception: If a question has been deleted but not properly cleaned up, help us out by editing the question to remove everything but the title.  Thanks!*

**See the [Sandbox FAQ](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/639/2685) for more information on how to use the Sandbox.**

---

## Maintenance

This section is referred to when a new sandbox is created.  [In order to make the Sandbox easier to use](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3813/6507), a new Sandbox question will be posted when the old one becomes too full (between 75 and 100 sandbox questions).

***Whomever creates the new page:** be sure you want to be actively involved with the Sandbox, because until it gets replaced in the future, you'll be notified of every proposed question and every comment.*

**(A) Update this previous sandbox list:**

The previous sandbox post should be locked as obsolete by a moderator and renamed to "Inactive Sandbox [Date]." Please add a link to the top of the old sandbox page to the new Sandbox.

- [Inactive Sandbox 2019-2022](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7183/40609)
- [Inactive Sandbox 2018](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168)
- [Inactive Sandbox 2017-18](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4835)
- [Inactive Sandbox 2014-2017](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/635)

If there are active questions in the old Sandbox, leave a comment for the users indicating that the old sandbox is closing and they either need to wrap up (preferred) or re-post the question in the new Sandbox.

**(B) Update these links after the new Sandbox is created:**

- [Help Center/on-topic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (This requires the help of a moderator)
- [Sandbox FAQ](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/639#640) (The Sandbox FAQ has two links to the currently active sandbox: one in the question proper and one in the answer the above link takes you to.)
- The sort-by-active link at the top of the new Sandbox.
- The current sandbox link in our "[Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE!](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/welcome-to-worldbuilding-se)" page.
- Update the [worldbuilding-process](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/worldbuilding-process) [Wiki page](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tags/worldbuilding-process/info) to point to the new Sandbox page.

**(C) Create the "Graduated Question List" answer and mark it a "Community Wiki."**

Comment: I have locked the previous sandboxes as "obsolete". This should avoid confusion with the duplicate, since they hardly have the same content. For future reference, just flag the to-be-closed sandbox for mod attention requesting it to be obsoleted.

Comment: **Reminder to readers : Please do not vote on proposed questions.** At least 2 persons/accounts skipped the sandbox's rules recently. For everyone's sake please read them and apply them carefully.

Comment: Maintenance question: is it appropriate to up/downvote a proposed question to get it to zero?

Comment: @elemtilas I do. People aren't supposed to be voting and bias of any kind isn't the point here, but it's hard to break a habit.

Comment: @elemtilas :-) Your edit is the third time "please don't vote" is mentioned in the post. I'm OK with it... but I doubt anything will change. Based on how users use the Sandbox, very few of them read the instructions. *C'est la vie.*

Comment: @JBH --- I didn't see the third one! (oops!) I figured that if the message were closer to the top, it might get seen and processed early on.

Comment: Question : What should be done when no one comments under your post? Should the question follow the sandbox procedure (->adding it to the question list, etc.), or should it be discarded silently and posted on main, without any link to the sandbox?

Comment: @Tortliena You've discovered the weakness in the system. The Sandbox only works when a bunch of people are regularly participating. That was once true - but today few have the time to participate. I'd hate to suggest that the Sandbox's time has come and gone, but were I a querent with an unaddressed question in the Sandbox after 30 or 60 days, I'd post it on Main - and if anybody complained on Main, I'd post a link back to the Sandbox with the question, "where've you been?"

Comment: @JBH I'll follow your advice ^^. This also implies I can't get my own questions reviewed, since it looks like I'm kinda the last one here . I can almost hear the tumbleweeds rolling, western movie style .

Comment: @Tortliena It seriously hurt the value of the Sandbox when our Stack Exchange Overlords decided to discontinue the community ads. That was how we kept people reminded to stop in. Those ads were very effective. I assume SE wanted the space for monetization purposes, but that's only a pessimistic guess.

Comment: I concur: if a query has sat here uncommented on, the OP is well within rights to post it on main, and if anyone there complains, put it back on them that they didn't help when help was sought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Graduated Questions List**

In accordance with [Sandbox policy](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1728), answers containing graduated questions will be deleted. This answer is designed to be a repository for all those questions that have graduated. It is a community wiki answer, so add in your question here, at the end of the list, once it is posted on the main site! Position #1 is an example of how to do this to get the ball rolling.

1. [Sandbox for proposed Questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9981/40609)
2. [How large of a magma chamber do I need to geothermally power a small city?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/241544/how-large-of-a-magma-chamber-do-i-need-to-geothermally-power-a-small-city)
3. [How can muscle atrophy due to long gestation in artificial wombs be avoided?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/242595/how-can-muscle-atrophy-due-to-long-gestation-in-artificial-wombs-be-avoided)
4. [Knocking Out Zombies](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/243674/knocking-out-zombies)
5. [How to map arms of the galaxy?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/244457/how-to-map-arms-of-the-galaxy)
6. [How would I go about establishing phenotype in the case of co-dominance where mixed phenotype is not an option?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/245045/how-would-i-go-about-establishing-phenotype-in-the-case-of-co-dominance-where-mi)
7. [How can I determine gene expression in cases of multiple co-dominant genes?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/245059/80336)
8. [Surviving Organ Failure](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/246799/surviving-organ-failure)
9. [How to Optimize CO2 and H2 Intake for a Sessile Methane-Producing Organism](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/249553/how-to-optimize-co2-and-h2-intake-for-a-sessile-methane-producing-organism)
10. [Solutions for an Aquatic Race to Harvest the Sugar Under Sea Grass Meadows](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/246426/80336) (edited for reopening)
11. [How to recreate a "land" harp that can work in the deep sea?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/251409/how-to-recreate-a-land-harp-that-can-work-in-the-deep-sea)

Answer (score 0):

Title:

## Scientifically plausible way to bring the Earth to a 28- to 30-hour solar day

> Doomsday clocks [are sort of a common theme](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/159428/the-moon-will-fall-to-earth-in-100-years-how-fast-is-the-asteroid-that-knocked) in my stories. When I saw @eHaraldo post the sandbox [question about slowing down earth’s rotation to create a 30-hour day](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10088/69877), and then apparently abandon it; I am now adopting it. Because it’s a good question.

---

I'm worldbuilding a post-apocalyptic story set in the near future (~200 years). In my story, the Earth's rotation speed has been slowed down to 28- to 30-hours per day. I'm trying to explain how this happened. Note: the 200 years is approximate, and it allows for the day to be slowed down less abruptly. i.e., **there is no need for a single, abrupt event **.

The scale of the event, given the above numbers will require **an input of 30.014 billion zetajoules of energy** applied against the earth's rotation through that ≅200 years. It won't all go to slowing the planet, figure something bigger to offset waste.

My research suggests that it may be possible through several events though I will need the confirmation of an expert opinion before considering it an answer.

- A barrage/trail of asteroid impacts
- A neutron star flyby
- The moon doing something horrible
- A disruption of the Earth's core

### My setting requirements

Given: the cataclysmic event has wiped out most of humanity, and will have caused a series of major geophysical disasters, including tidal waves, earthquakes, volcanoes, and weather tragedies.

Some humans and enough of a biosphere to keep them alive must have survived, but mass devastation of the planet including extinction of many species is acceptable and expected.

The Earth's orbit may or may not have been affected, **but tidal locking did not happen.**

**The above consequences are acceptable side-effects to the alteration of the solar day.**

### The expected consequences will be:

- Food shortages and famine
- Water shortages and drought
- Disease outbreaks
- Social unrest and violence
- Economic collapse
- Environmental degradation

### Q: What cataclysm might create this world within 200 years?

---

> I assume the tags for this will be [planets] [apocalypse] [solar-system] [science-based]

Comment: 1. Suggest that the "My setting requirements" can be condensed down to "Some humans and enough of a biosphere to keep them alive must have survived, but mass devastation of the planet including extinction of many species is acceptable and expected."  2. Heading is saying "scientifically plausible" but there are no tags for level of realism.  3. Suggest specifying whether it can be done deliberately by very, very powerful aliens, since I can't see a way to leave any biosphere if the change results from a single event.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 I've incorporated those suggestions and added some research. [I had a very similar question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/159428/the-moon-will-fall-to-earth-in-100-years-how-fast-is-the-asteroid-that-knocked) a while back, this might fit that plotline.

Comment: Is this Sandbox question still active?

Comment: It is for me. Still awaiting feedback on the last edit.

Comment: @VogonPoet It's been a long time. (a) Providing your own answers and asking for more is prohibited in the [help/dont-ask]. That all needs to be removed. (b) Asking for "the most realistic" anything is off-topic because that's an impossible-to-judge criteria. What's realistic to you? What's realistic to me? What's realistic to my little sister or a Tibetian monk who likes reading scifi? How will you objectively judge a best answer? (c) The "Obvious Things" section should be deleted. It's irrelevant to the question as they're all implied by requirement #2.

Comment: Otherwise it's a perfectly reasonable question for the site.

Answer (score 0):

## [What qualities would an AGI need to gain legal protections today?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/248957/how-could-an-agi-have-legal-protections-in-an-our-current-society)

| Sandbox notes: |
| --- |
| This question was closed as "opinion based" however it is important to my many other AGI questions. I need this world built. Any help is great. |
| - Related question for this world |
| - [What are the parenting options available to species that reproduce by fragmentation?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/249715/what-are-the-parenting-options-available-to-species-that-reproduce-by-fragmentat) |
| - [What faith do my AI follow that is most belligerent to human traditions and beliefs?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/249748/what-faith-do-my-ai-follow-that-is-most-belligerent-to-human-traditions-and-beli) |
| Per the [Meta reference on "stoy based closing"](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3300/69877), [this question is on topic](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3301/69877), as it asks: "What could cause a government [English common law] to pass such-and-such law [AGI rights] given these societal conditions [an AGI of X definition is created]" |

First: assume society is as it is today, British common law; United States might be easiest but any government will suffice.

My story has [an AGI species](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/249715/what-are-the-parenting-options-available-to-species-that-reproduce-by-fragmentat) interacting with humans and their definition needs to snub any qualms about, "The police wouldn't do that because legally..."

A good answer provides the "what" portion of the on-topic example question in the Meta about "[Why is my question too 'Story-based'](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3300/69877)"; which is formed as:

> *What could cause **a government** to pass **such-and-such law** given these **societal conditions**?*

Where:

- **What** Is the answer you give, narrowly defining qualities of an AGI
- **government** is English common law government
- **such-and-such law** is, specifically, the Bill of Rights principle of "We hold these truths to be self-evident, that all *men* are created equal" classifying these fictional AGI as "men" in the same way it now classifies women as "men" in modern interpretation.
- The **societal conditions** are that a new artificial species has been created and propagated throughout society.

A good question avoids

1. changes to society
2. relating this species to current AI or its methods
3. simplistic "just write a law" answers (laws don't protect anything under common law; blind protections of the law works only in dictatorships)

### The Common Law principle that applies here

| This is an aside for clarification |
| --- |
| Laws of society can only grant rights if there is some means to remedy the violation of the right. For example, a law that protects a human’s right to breathe water can’t be tried in court even if some human finds out they can’t breathe water. The law simply can not possibly “fix” the thing that’s been “taken” from you - an impossible ability to breathe water. That is a ridiculous example, I know, but ridiculous laws do happen. The point is, simply saying you have a “right” to this or that doesn’t create any legal right unless you're in a dictatorship. The common law principle originated in Roman law as **ubi jus ibi remedium**, “where there is a right, there is a remedy”, and remains in effect today when our courts decide if you have been violated. But this principle applies to my problem through its logically equivalent contrapositive: **Si nulla remedium existit, tunc nulla ius existit**. Thus the existence of rights is contingent upon the availability of remedies to enforce and protect those rights. Without a remedy, any purported rights become meaningless and unenforceable. Ergo; we do not put dead murderers on trial, punish insane felons, or sue dead offenders, or punish people who safely [shoot their own computer](https://twitter.com/CSPDPIO/status/590544244227575808?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E590544244227575808%7Ctwgr%5E838f8bd8fdb55fef488df148ce5f30c26cbf7f86%7Ctwcon%5Es1_&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.nbcnews.com%2Fnews%2Fus-news%2Fcolorado-man-ends-battle-computer-shooting-it-8-times-n345841). What could the judge take from one and give to the other to remedy your loss? |
| A real-world example: we have a right to have our credit information accurately reported. This law is called the Fair Credit Reporting Act (FCRA). But even if the credit company gives false information about your credit, the court can’t and won't give you anything. *Spokeo, Inc. v. Robins (2016)* ruled that even though misleading figures were published by the credit card company, the plaintiff could not show that they actually *lost* anything from inaccurate or incomplete information in their credit reports. There is no right to relief until you have actually “lost” something. |

| thought experiment |
| --- |
| This is about designing a fictional Artificial General Intelligence (AGI), and answering what “ingredient”—for lack of a better word—would afford it rights under existing common law: Let’s assume we invent the asked fictional AGI, and we put them into a mechanical body. Now let’s assume a group lobbies and passes a law that makes it illegal to willfully dismember and destroy the AGI, and treat such an act as a “wrongful death.” They classify this as a crime just like it would be for a human (because again, no laws are changed) When an AGI is destroyed, someone claiming a relationship to it wants the system to prosecute for wrongful death. Well, there clearly exists a “wrongful death” law in the books because it was passed. But the judge’s first job is to decide if some remedy exists to what was “lost.” This means the judge has to be convinced that at first, the AGI even *had* a right to life before asking if a life has been lost. **So the question came to me:** If an AGI is a computer program, and computer programs can be and are backed up and saved regularly, so effectively they can only be lost by deliberate manipulation of the server; does a computer program have a “right to life?” This doesn't work! Something has to be different about these AGI. |

---

## What about our world (specifically, about the qualities of an AGI in this world) needs to be changed

to give artificially generated algorithms and programs a right to life, that could be recognized and fairly remedied in a human justice system? (Answers do not need to fix the problem, the question only asks what needs fixing)

Emphasis again, I don’t believe our real world could possibly argue for the right of an artificial construct to exist, as they currently exist. The question tries to pin down what prevents this, and removes that quality from what we call an "AI" (by changing the AGI, or maybe the environment - anything *except* the basic principles of jurisprudence)

### I can’t state this enough. This question is NOT asking about current AI or anything existing today.

Comment: So you came to the sandbox ^^. I'll be sadly honest, not many people come here, so you probably won't have much help besides mine. I'll try my best though . If we sum up a bit your situation, since you accumulated a good chunk of small edits and clarifications, it'd be wise to make a brand new V2 to start on a new leaf. However, you mustn't invalidate existing answers, and at the same time I guess you do wanna ask this exact question... We're in a kinda tough spot . Guess the best thing to do right now is to improve it then check whether it should be an edit or a new question altogether.

Comment: The first thing I'd do is to focus on what this question is about rather than what it isn't about. The main topic should take at least half of the question : This will help people understand what you're looking for and prevent undesired topics to indirectly stain your question. Still, I believe it'll be useful to keep one (and only one) paragraph telling you're not looking for a change of law but a change of A.G.I., if I understand what you want correctly.

Comment: To improve directly on the "opinion-based" part, the classic thing to do is to tell as accurately as possible what your criteria for a best answer is. This often goes with superlative, e.g. : "[What's the **safest** way to carry and throw marble sized high-explosive grenades?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/201395/80336)". Note this "superlative" should be defined as clearly as you can : "efficient" and "best" are commonly used, but they often are thought to be too blurry. Might be hard to pull off here, but if you do that it'll definitely win you some points .

Comment: For the resting rest, I guess we'll have to see how it goes and work from there ^^. I'm not confident enough right now to tell you whether the two things above will get your question reopened, yet I don't have many advices at this point that will ensure whatever you do it'll get better.

Comment: The entire question is the last sentence; which is a less specific wording of the title: "It’s a fictional AGI that can fit into our society; why does it fit?" (e.g., because it can reciprocate?) i.e., why is it legally protected in existing law. A good answer shows what quality the AGI has that makes it fit (e.g., because it can reciprocate?). I could move all the negatives to a "a good answer avoids.." block at the bottom, The risk is people scanning the first bit & hastily posting answers that invalidate rearranging the question. So the "DO NOT" is critical to avoid crippling non-answers.

Comment: When you talk too much about "it's not X", it means you haven't clearly defined "it's Y". I know you can describe something about what it's not, like "dogs are not insects, not birds, not fishies...", but you'll never really get to the core if you don't define what it is : "a dog is a carnivorous mammal". This will make your question much shorter (so easier to read and understand) and clearer (people will not as easily bind themselves to some off-topic questions just because they were written). This is why this part should be summarized ^^.

Comment: Updated. The "It's Y" is stated as "artificially generated algorithms and programs," and that's the only unchangeable aspect of them. The other "It's Y" is: "compatible with modern legal protections without changing the law."

Comment: There are many legal systems which all operate differently. Within a legal system each government has their own set of laws which operate differently. Even within a specific legal system and set of laws there can be differing precedence depending on the court that hears such a case. The scope of your question is far too broad without this.

Comment: I cannot think of any system for determining whether a non-person shall be granted the same rights as a person under the law. If such a system exists then that system will have your answer. If such a system doesn't exist then any petition of personhood under the law will require some controversy requiring the adjudication of the courts. This will include persuasive arguments on how to interpret and extend existing laws to cover a novel situation, both for and against the granting of personhood in this specific case.

Comment: In other words in the absence of explicit laws on the subject the traits necessary to grant an AI legal rights will be the result of how a judge chooses to rule based on the competing actions of at least two individuals. Keep in mind that these arguments will be focused on the specifics of the case. The judge, if convinced will then establish an appropriate standard. That much character motivated action has nothing to do with any fact of your world and everything to do with hoy you decide events within your world will play out.  Such a question is unsuitable for this site.

Comment: IOW the case would resolve to Virginia v. Loving or State of Tennessee v. John Thomas Scopes in determining personhood. I agree, it would do that. I need the question to steer away from the assumption the answer has to win a Supreme Court ruling on one case. The world needs a definition of a being that could have standing in that court and nothing more. With standing, there is protection; standing isn’t a choice, it’s constitutionally defined - federal in the case of “men created equal”. I chose those tags for that reason.

Comment: "The world needs a definition of a being that could have standing in that court an dnothing more." You don't understand that your problem is a failure to understand the underpinnings of law and how it came to pass. I have a family full of attorneys and it's been fascinating to discuss with them over the decades the "rights" or "needs" of the poor, the homeless, the wealthy.... most of whom aren't treated as "people" today, but as a "class," disassociating and disenfranchising them from the basic rights of "people." That's why I agree with the initial closure reason of ... (\*Continued\*)

Comment: ... opinion-based, but it could just as easily be closed for violating the book rule. The problem is that you're looking at law today with a snapshot view and believe that all you need is a paragraph of text to solve your problem. This, despite what paragraphs we have having been developed after millenia of blood and centuries of debate and experimentation. You're asking us to put the cart before the horse and you're expecting some form of definitive answer when, in reality, the development of the legal structure you're looking for would be a novel (and an interesting one) ... (\*Continued\*)

Comment: ... all by itself. But, if we are to attempt to ask and answer this question, it must begin in a way that reflects your astute observation of there needing something to lose. Most (if not all) Western law is based on the premise that the person or organization seeking redress can define, not what they could lose, *but what they've factually lost due to something in the past* and that an argument can be made that what was lost had either intrinsic or factual value. But, most poingant, is the reality that without the ability to convince in court ... (\*Continued\*)

Comment: ... that something had intrinsic or factual value, what's left is a revolution to establish in a foundation belief that value. I regret that you appear to be trying to patch an existing system when what you will be required to do is rebuild it.

Comment: Thank you both for the time, just a quick response to @sphennings initial “system of determination” observation. I believe in a gray world; clear lines don’t exist. But where two answers exist; a line divides them. One side: a laptop with advanced AI programming. This won’t ever be considered. Second side: 30-YO brain dead Alice gets an artificial brain. “Alice” goes to court. Readers would believe she(?) would be heard. The story lives in the cutoff between A & B. Still reading the responses, just making that observation [End]

Comment: I've finally got a good computer screen to read around your text (the sandbox is so hard to read on small screens with big, sore eyes x) ). I don't know if you're still set on this question, believe you do. I want to ask about the paragraphs between the sandbox note's insert and "*The Common Law principle that applies here*" title : Is it still part of the sandbox's note or is it what you would add to your edited question? This has confused me a bit, especially since you're making a case for your question before stating said question .

Comment: It’s an aside for now. With a difficult question like this I was trying to explain the problem, that it’s not just answered with “so pass the law.” I actually answered this question myself with my [_Cerebrum Naturae_ species](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/249684/what-ai-force-strength-would-be-needed-to-defeat-modern-humanity), which I believe has a reasonable chance at emancipation.

Comment: Is this Sandbox question still active?

Comment: Yes, it is still waiting for a suggestion or nod.

Comment: I think that these questions might be answerable in terms of the conditions that would have to exist for an AI to be ruled a person. For instance, if an AI were to be labeled a corporation, it would have the right to own property. The Scopes Money Trial (et. al.) was decided based on rhetoric and case law. We are getting dangerously close to AIs being able to craft winning arguments. A financially successful AI could hire lawyers and arrange a legal victory in this area. We don't have to know the argument that the AI would present, we just have to know the circumstances of their creation.

Comment: (continued) Granted, this comes dangerously close to being a question about a story instead of a world, but that's a different issue.

Comment: I disagree that any condition in the world would allow the things we know as AI to be granted any rights, and I specifically am not looking for granting rights to anything like "Bard" or "ChatGPT" - even after many years of learning and improvement. The fact that they use proprietary software and hardware alone means they are "property" of some entity, and owned things. he can't possess anything, let alone themselves. But thanks!

Comment: I'm still having a hard time seeing this as anything other than a story-based question. Here's my problem: I come from a family full of lawyers. Lawyers do their job by *making decisions* (prohibited in the [help/on-topic] about how to craft arguments and about what laws to challenge - and this presupposes that such an argument could win against the "court of public opinion," which decision can only be created by [narrative necessity](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7281/40609). But, worst of all, law is NOT objective. It's hugely subjective, based on assumptions ...

Comment: ... about what are "people" and what are "rights" and what is "fair" or "just." In other words, I don't just strongly doubt that an objective list of issues could be created, I know it can't be created. Honestly, take the time to read the entire (and I mean that, *the entire*) collected robot stories by Asimov. He spent vast amounts of time tickling the idea of what kind of society would accept AI and what kind wouldn't, and what would that mean for either society? Indeed, Asimov's works are perhaps the best evidence that this isn't an objective question. ...

Comment: On top of all that, the only person who would be qualified to answer this question would be a barrister or judge being a citizen of the British Commonwealth. That's a pretty narrow field of experts. I'm a programmer and an electrical engineer, and I"m not at all convinced that I could give a convincing answer to this question. This might be a case where you're asking for too much realism. Who among your readers would know any particular answer was right or wrong if they weren't also a British lawyer? Indeed, most will judge based on their own preconceptions of AI and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

## Title:
Is this time travel mechanic plausible?

I was trying to ask a question for a novel I am trying to make, but it was closed for many reasons. I need help making it ask-worthy. This is my question with various revisions that I made after it was closed, but with some parts remaining in hopes that they can still remain in the finished question.

---

I am trying to make a novel, and I wanted to know if this is a good hard science theory for time travel. Given that (as far as I know) white holes are theorized to have negative mass; and that anything with negative mass travels faster than the speed of light*, would that mean that white holes can travel faster than the speed of light? If not, why? This is disregarding causality, I already have a workaround.

*1 : This is due to the same principle that makes massless particles travel the speed of light. I believe it has something to do with inertia, in which case this would make sense, but either way, this was used in a theory for tachyons and was not criticized.

Comment: (a) There is no such thing as hard science in regard to time travel. There is not even a suggestion of proof for time travel. Asking this question in any context other than [tag:science-fiction] will raise the risk of closure and down votes.  (b) You start by saying you're trying to set a rule for time travel, but you don't describe one. Your question is if the supposition of negative mass (ficitonal) justifies FTL (fictional) of white holes (fictional). (c) Tachyons are also fictional, so upholding them as the rationale for treating your question as hard science fails your intent.

Comment: Your biggest problem is that you're missing about three years of college-level classes in astrophysics and mathematics. You want us to provide, not just a realistic solution, but a real solution to a problem that you don't know isn't real due to the lack of that education - and Stack Exchange is not the place to get it, even in the form of sound bites. If you step away from insisting that all this be real and ask the question as "In my world negative mass exists, which leads to white holes ...

Comment: moving FTL, which leads to the following detailed explanation for time travel, is this consistent?" then we have a question we can work with for this Stack.

Comment: Plausible is a subjective quality that has nothing to do with the facts of your world but the knowledge of your audience and how receptive they are to how you present your world. We're here to help you establish facts about your world not determine how people will feel about your presentation of them. Remember that magic and FTL are both physical impossibilities and yet their existence in well written works of fiction does nothing to detract from our enjoyment of them. Similarly there is no level of plausibility that will salvage a poorly written story.

Comment: @JBH The only reason that tachyons and faster-than-light travel are believed to be impossible is because they are believed to violate the laws of physics (specifically causality), but if the fifth dimension were brought up, (comprising of many timelines) then causality can be avoided, as changing the past is impossible, you just follow along in a branch.

Comment: And as I have explained in another thread, absence of evidence is not evidence of absence. Plus, even if there were not any theorized ways to create these things (there are), it is a science fiction novel. Any part the author can’t explain just gets ignored.

Comment: I am not using tachyons to prove my idea, I am using the accepted parts of the theory, which is unrelated to the actual tachyons.

Comment: I provided the solution, I want you to tell me if it makes sense. And because positive mass exists, negative mass must exist as well. Which means that ftl must exist, and wormholes _could_  exist. Also, I am not insisting that these things exist, they have never been proven, yet they have never been disproven either, which is perfect for a hard science sci fi novel.

Comment: Your turn, @sphennings. Magic, which has a variable definition, usually means something that violates the laws of thermodynamics. That is more than likely a physical impossibility. FTL, however, is already possible with negative mass, and we have no good evidence that it is impossible, at least with the fifth dimension. So as long as negative mass is impossible, true FTL is too. So before you say it is impossible, you have to disprove negative mass. Feel free to do so.

Comment: I wanted someone to tell me if this was formatted right. Save the criticisms for the actual question.

Comment: The sandbox is used to help you improve your questions, this includes ensuring that you are asking questions that is appropriate for this site. There are more significant issues than formatting with your question. Asking "Is X plausible?" is not a worldbuilding question and should not be asked on this site. Please remember that not every question about worldbuilding is suitable for this site. Questions that are too broad or opinion based are also not permitted and will be closed. We don't want to waste our time addressing formatting issues on questions inappropriate for this site.

Comment: @WhatsYourIQ192 Sorry for the delay. As elements gathered from another post indicates... Some viewpoint about new users, I'd like to first tell you I'm sorry about the way you're currently being received in the sandbox. This isn't probably not what you were looking for when coming here. Relativity theory is not my forte, but I'll try to help you reach your goals and improve your work  anyway. Just give me some time!

Comment: Ok, the first thing I can easily suggest is to remove notions of hard-science in your question. Don't worry, it will not affect your work. As the other two said, hard-science is... Harder than you think. Hypothetical objects (like [white holes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_hole)) rarely have a place there, as no one have managed to prove their existence. It's more some kind of mathematical thoughts. Removing this term will effectively reduce the ire from people who expect something ultra-hard. [...]

Comment: [...] If it helps you ease your mind about negative mass/white holes not existing : In sciences, it's always difficult to know whether something is real. Example? I hereby tell you on my honor that "*rainbow, colored turtle-unicorns exist on Earth*". Of course they don't, but what actually tells you that? I guess you're not ready to check every acres of dirt that there's a turtlenicorn in hiding. So instead you use what you observed before : of all animals on Earth you witnessed, none were house-sized, rainbow colored chimeras, so the odds of finding one will be astronomically low.[...]

Comment: [...] Now, if you do find that turtlenicorn, congratulations, you've been wrong, which means you can improve your view on the world! Science is a masochist like that : While the absence of evidence doesn't tell you it doesn't exist 9000% sure, this lack of evidence tells us it's very improbable and so can be dismissed... Until proven otherwise. As soon that you found this proof, you get a Nobel Prize because you broke everything we knew about the world!

Comment: First of all, if you know that it is impossible, then that is evidence of absence. For example, if someone claimed that it could produce raw energy out of nothing without some divine power, then you know that person is wrong. Second of all, it would not be a turtlenicorn, it would be a turtlecorn.

Comment: It is harder to use science to disprove things than it is to prove things. Knowledge doesn’t provide much information about things you don’t have knowledge about. You cannot easily disprove that somewhere and somewhen, you could’ve seen a star formation that roughly forms the word “star”.

Comment: Science says that things that violate the known laws of physics and logic are impossible, but anything outside of that may be possible. This means that if you can find something that does not violate the known laws of physics and logic, it is possible.

Comment: that means that using a work-around for causality makes time travel possible. And actually, because time is a physical dimension, time travel being impossible is impossible itself. We just have not figured out how to do it yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149478/discussion-between-tortliena-and-whatsyouriq192).

Comment: I've moved the [discussion into the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149478/discussion-between-tortliena-and-whatsyouriq192) (thanks magic link!), you can click on it and continue there if you wish to. With 25 points you should have the right to discuss in chatrooms.

Comment: `I provided the solution, I want you to tell me if it makes sense.` It doesn't make sense from a Real World perspective, which is what you're asking us to accept. You're really fighting this. Per the [help/on-topic], our goal is to help you develop the rules of an *imaginary world.* You can set those rules as you wish. You have ***not*** explained time travel, so there are no rules for us to judge. You ***are*** asking of a hypothesized Real World condition can exist. What are you expecting? The answer is "we don't know." Now, if you want to set a rule for your imaginary world....

Comment: And before you get going on that last comment, please ***try to remember*** that validating a "good hard science theory" is ***not*** our job. We will gladly help you develop and consistently use rules of an imaginary world of your own creation. We're not going to let you ask on Main if your strong belief in a hypothesis is "good hard science."

Comment: Is this question still active?

Answer (score 0):

> I have posted this question in sandbox because:
>
> 1. I'm not sure whether this is more suited to worldbuilding or the math stack-exchange site.
> 2. This question, while simple to me, may feel convoluted because it's asking for a general algorithm as opposed to a single answer to a single query.

### Title: "Simple model for trait propagation in a population"

In a worldbuilding project of mine, humans can have a pseudo-magical trait that, if present in either mother or father, is 100% of the time passed on to a child (unlike genetic traits, which are generally more complicated than that).

In order to be able to estimate how quickly this trait is propagated in a given population of humans, I'd like to have a simplified model that I can apply to different sizes of populations.

I have the rules I would need to run a simulation of this model, and I could probably program it if I have to. But I suspect that there's likely to be a mathematical/probability-based way to do it without needing the simulation, and thought I would ask if anyone here would be able to point me in the right direction.

#### The model

Suppose we have a fixed population size of ***2n***, consisting of ***n*** males and ***n*** females. Associated with each member of the population is a simple ***true*** or ***false*** value indicating the presence of the trait.

Each generation, the males and females are randomly paired off and each pair produces exactly 2 offspring - one male and one female. These offspring are the (exactly 2n) members of the next generation, and each is given a value of ***true*** if and only if either or both of their parents had it.

With the above model, I could run simulations to answer questions like,

- "For a population of 1000 with 1 trait-positive individual, how many generations would it take (on average) for the whole population to be trait-positive?"
- "For a population of 500 with 100 trait-positive males and 250 trait-positive females, how many individuals (on average) would be trait-positive after 3 generations?"

#### The question

**Is there a mathematical algorithm or approach I could use** to answer these kinds or questions, using this model, **without needing to simulate it generation-by-generation?**

Comment: Hi Qami! Just on the surface of things, I would say remember that WB.SE is for the **rules of your world: how things are the way they are, how they work, what might be done with them.** Since you've already got the world and have already determined a specific rule of your world, I would argue that WB is not the right forum for this question. That said, I'm sure you would get an answer here! I think math.se would be the better choice, though. At least at first: if they have a conniption about your scenario, I would not complain if they exported the question to WB.

Comment: Cool problem. At it's core you're asking a straight math problem and will probably get better mileage asking mathematicians about it. While I wouldn't recommend asking it on the main site I've definitely been nerd snipped by this problem. I'd love to see what comes of this if you post it on a math or statistics focused exchange. You could also post it in the worldbuilding chat and see if anyone wanders by and gets distracted.

Comment: Past the first generation there will always be an equal number of men and women with the trait. The maximum growth of the trait in a generation will be a doubling, with the average being a function of how likely it is for there to pair off two trait having individuals each generation.

Comment: @sphennings You've hit the nail on the head with the second comment, about the initial doubling and diminishing returns as the proportion increases. This is exactly what I want to get the math for. I'll wait another day or so to see if I have more input, but otherwise I'll post on math.stackexchange.

Comment: While it's technically worldbuilding (you're indirectly asking how the world is at some time "t" because of that trait), you've contrived the problem so much to a math model it will not be accepted here. So indeed maths.SE it is. Let's just hope that they are not seeing only the world, not the maths (some on other sites have tunnel vision on that), because the worst thing that can happen to you is get migrated to WB:SE, then closed here for being off-topic and migrated back to never be reopened again...

Comment: Do note that because eventually everyone will have the trait, it will probably not be considered the best worldbuilding question out there. Indeed, and that's what Elemtilas showed, people tend to think the world in absolute terms, rather than something that evolves over time. That's a lot due to the fact worlds are made for stories, and stories are set in a specific point of time, giving this "absolute" feeling. Most changes to the world are then made by the story, rather than an ominous, unwavering world rule.

Comment: If you want to have more prior research, there's a youtube channel called [Primer](https://www.youtube.com/@PrimerBlobs) which focuses a lot on evolution of traits within people, with funny looking blobs and a bit of Unity Engine. I'm not sure you'll find the formulas you want there, but it can really help understand the various cases of evolution.

Comment: To be clear - and using my starting conditions rather than yours - we might have 500 magic people in a population significantly larger than 500. Those 500 are guaranteed to have two and only two offspring regardless who they're paired with. Both offspring are guaranteed to be magic so long as one parent is magic. So, best case first gen result is 2500 and worst case is 1000 and since a a random number is involved it's a random result between those two limits (for the first gen). Did I get that right?

Comment: I expect respondents will complain about the offspring condition of your model. If no couple can have more or less than two offspring, you have zero population growth and decline other than the first few until your average max age begins removing non-breeding pairs, in which case this is a model that will only answer the question "how many generations until my population is X% saturated?"

Comment: Frankly, I'd research virus propagation in populations. There must be a statistical estimator for that purpose - whole games have been made based on the concept. In other words, this problem is fundamentally solved. You'll need to reword the question to remove the magic part of it ("I have a trait that propagates according to the following rules...") but I recommend you ask on [biology.se] or [medicalsciences.se].

Comment: Final advice: the problem with random numbers is that they only work statistically over large groups of something: people, time, etc. In other words, a software program would likely churn out the same result for your first bulleted result if asked multiple times... but it'll churn out a different result each time for the second bullet example because three generations isn't long enough for the effects of random initial conditions to wash out. Virus propagation estimators work because propagation works randomly within the space of hours but the simulations are looking at weeks or months.

Comment: @Tortliena Thank you for your feedback! The fact that everyone will eventually have the trait is indeed by design and is part of the evolution of this world. I'm planning many stories that take place in this world, at different points in its history, and the purpose of this mathematical model is just to help me maintain consistency over the timeline and the different populations that are exposed to the trait at different times.

Comment: @JBH Thank you for your feedback! There are of course many considerations - biological, cultural, demographics, and more - that will need to be factored in to get more useful estimates. This model is very deliberately simplified and unrealistic by itself. It's simply intended to be a baseline upon which to apply these other considerations. I like your idea of trying on medical sciences - I'll check there if math.se doesn't pan out!

Comment: Is this question still active?

Answer (score 0):

##### If 30% of global military spending for the next 30 years were instead spent on an "intelligent life" backup colony, where should we site it and why?

[Originally posted (and subsequently closed) question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/253404/if-30-of-global-military-spending-for-the-next-30-years-were-instead-spent-on-a).

Some discussion in [this meta post](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10321/how-can-we-make-the-where-to-site-a-backup-colony-question-more-focused/10326#10326).

#### Notes about the question (not for the description)

The plot of the story is 1) AI near-miss happens, 2) There is agreement to spend big on a solution, 3) Then debate on the best solution occurs, 4) Colonize Venus wins, 5) Earth colonizes Venus with solar powered aircraft.

**I'm looking for help with (3)**. I want the debate about alternatives to be as realistic as possible, so I need some more creative and well-supported counter proposals. It is the brainstorming and exchange of perspectives from the proponents of different ideas that I'd like the community's help with.

#### Question Description

Some industry leaders have proposed that AI poses a risk of extinction. Suppose some kind of an AI-related incident occurs that really scares humanity into action, and that this causes the world's governments to come together and agree to reallocate 30% of the many trillions of dollars that they spend on defense to developing a single insurance policy megaproject called "Plan B". Plan B must ensure that, even in the event of civilization-on-Earth ending calamity, intelligent life will nevertheless persevere.

What would be the best place to site this backup colony?

Keep in mind that whatever "Plan B" is, offering better natural immunity to AI-related threats will be an acceptance criterion. If it's a backup plan in case of other existential threats, such as nuclear war or an extinction-level comet or asteroid impact, that would be a bonus.

It would be valid (not necessarily the best site) if the colony was sited in an underground bunker on Earth or in orbit around the Earth. If the best site is off-world, assume that the cost of going to Mars, Venus, or the Moon is 1B per metric ton (MT). Global military spending in 2022 was 2.24 Trillion USD/Year. We can assume that somehow we will lower the cost-per-kg by a factor of 100 for such a large project, so if the entire budget was spent on interplanetary transportation, our mass budget would be around...

MassBudget=(30years)(0.3)($2.24T)(100)/($1B/MT)=2,160,000tons

Of course, the mass budget for a giant orbiting habitat or an underground bunker on Earth could be higher, and it is unrealistic to spend the entire budget on launch. Perhaps a 50/50 split would be more reasonable.

I'm looking for the best site when using an approach grounded in present-day physics, materials, engineering, and medical knowledge. The answer does not need to provide a detailed plan, it just needs to explain enough to illustrate the key advantages of the proposed site and establish why it is the best alternative.

---

***JBH's Proposed Edit***

**Background**

A story event occurs that causes the Earth's nations to unite in the effort to colonize another planet in our solar system. They have dedicated 730 Billion U.S. dollars annually (approximately [one-third the global military budget](https://www.statista.com/statistics/262742/countries-with-the-highest-military-spending/) to achieve this goal.

I have chosen Venus to be the planet for colonization.

- The project will take 30 years (22 Trillion USD total investment from concept to occupation of Venus).
- It will cost $?.??/ton to move the ship and its cargo to Venus.
- A maximum of 30% of any ship's total mass is payload.

**Question**

What are science-based reasons why Venus would be the superior choice compared to other planets?

*Please note that this is the first of two questions. The second question will ask for scientific reasons why Venus is not the better choice. If you're tempted to provide a frame challenge to this question, it should instead be submitted as an answer to the second.*

Comment: I'm glad you put this here! I have some questions. First, just for perspective, US military spending is about 40% of world total, so theoretically, the US could fund the project alone and still spend the usual amount on its military. The vast majority of countries spend almost nothing on military. The bottom 30 countries each spend less than a billion, the bottom 20 less than half a billion. The bottom 70 spend less than about 5 billion each. A question that arises here is: why are we focused on the money angle that you chose? Does it matter if Zambia cuts a cheque for 12 million? (cont)

Comment: The reason why I ask about the money focus is that a) your plot doesn't mention money or funding at all and b) your underlying query doesn't seem to be money focused either.  Your question seems to be about location. You might consider keeping the economics out of *this question* because it might lead to some confusion or might hamper the answers you get.  Second, since money will eventually be part of the story, are we to consider the limitations of budget when determining the location for this colony? To me, it seems like a very small budget for a colony on another planet. (cont)

Comment: Especially Venus which seems to be particularly hostile to human people and their machines. I'd therefore suggest splitting off the economics and making a follow-up question. So, my plan would be: **Q1** --- "If money were not at issue, where should this colony be sited, given the overall world constraints and plot layout?"  **Q2** --- "Given the global nature of the solution, what would be a sensible total budget for the project? Either a lump sum, or spread over x years."  **Q3** --- "Bonus! Would this be feasible if spending is limited to 30% of world military spending over 30 years?"

Comment: I think this plan would take your overall query and give the underlying factors the focus they deserve as well as the focus we need here for SE.

Comment: Thanks! The question was modified based on early "not focused enough" comments to include a budget and to focus on an AI incident. Are you proposing to put Q1-3 in the same post? I also received several answers along the lines of "You can't outrun an AI so what's the point?" which didn't really address my question. I'd also like to make sure people don't waste their time providing that kind of answer.

Comment: To summarize [what I just wrote on your Meta question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10321/how-can-we-make-the-where-to-site-a-backup-colony-question-more-focused/10326?noredirect=1#comment35800_10326): as written, (3) is storybuilding, we don't allow debates or discussions, and brainstorming is hugely limited. We can help explain why Venus is a good spot, but we're not in the business of helping you write your story. Thus, the question must be written from the perspective of, (\*Continued\*)

Comment: ... "my society has X resources to work with and I want Y to be the result. What about X and Y can I use to rationalize decision Y?" With your permission, I'll gladly edit this post to show you a version of what would be acceptable. You can always roll the edit back to the original if you don't like it.

Comment: Permission granted!

Comment: No, I'm suggesting that Q1, Q2, & Q3 be separate queries. I figured you probably got a comment about the budget. The reason I recommend splitting that into its own question is that it really doesn't help us with the location of the project, especially when so much money is being spent over a long period of time.  I agree with you about the AI comment. If those were actual answers, you can certainly downvote them! You can add a comment saying something like "this has nothing to do with the question at all." But never fear! We here at Worldbuilding are *experts* at wasting our time on all (cont)

Comment: (cont) kinds of answers! The best way to do this however, at least in my opinion, is to think of your title question as the main thing you want answered. The body of your question should always support your title. So, extraneous considerations, like budgets and like AI itself, are best left out, or put into a subsequent question. Generally, well written questions have four parts: 1. is the title; 2. is a short background / description of the world or setting; 3. is the main points you want us to consider (this could be your goals, things that you're not interested in, etc) and (cont)

Comment: (cont) 4. is a recapitulation of the question, usually with a bit more detail that is placed in the title and 5. is a short section where you tell us the measuring stick by which you'll measure our answers - what makes a good answer, what makes a bad answer. (NB: I couldn't edit my previous, so read "five" in stead of "four".)

Comment: I've made a proposed edit and I apologize that this too so honking long. Please remember to use @*name* to ping people. (e.g., @phil1008) I produced an edit that reflects the objective one-specific-problem-to-solve format Stack Exchange requires. To be honest, I don't know if you're going to get altogether useful answers as I find it difficult to believe Venus would ever win out over Mars. But that's the purpose of the question. I do have some concerns. (a) You're not using "mass budget" the way the space industry does. ...

Comment: ... I tried to convert that to something sensible like dollars-per-ton to move payload to Venus, but there are a lot of variables that people will complain about not knowing, like exactly how much mass we're talking about. Expecting us to figure out how much payload over the entire project will be expected is way, way, way out of scope. I'm not even sure it's possible. Therefore, this is really a "money is no object" question looking for purely scientific reasons why Venus is good/bad. (b). OK, (b) was "you'll have a hard time beating Mars" issue. Got ahead of myself. Ah! ...

Comment: ... (c) You might have a problem with on-topic [finite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6138/40609) vs. off-topic [infinite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6139/40609) perspective. We really don't like brainstorming questions. However, this kinda isn't brainstorming but is, IMO, a finite list of things question.

Comment: I like your draft question. Question: Since I already have a number of good reasons for picking Venus, should I provide [my justification](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/253404/if-30-of-global-military-spending-for-the-next-30-years-were-instead-spent-on-a/253415#253415) and ask if it is solid or if there are any other good reasons that I might not have thought of?

Answer (score 0):

## Species that never became immune to its own venom - is it plausible?

#### Tags: Science-based, creature-design

I am developing a fictional species for a video game I want to develop for a personal project. The biology that is relevant for this is that the species (called Rinans for now for the sake of convenience) is humanoid. They have a venom gland where the paritoid gland on a human is, along with a duct leading to the upper canines. As one of the game mechanics, Rinans produce venom when stressed and in pain (not all the time). They are also at least partially affected by their own venom if it enters their bloodstream. How can this lack of immunity be plausible?

Some important things to note:

- Rinans have been around for about as long as humans.
- They are omnivorous but they only use their venom when defending themselves from danger.
- They can start producing venom from childhood.
- They are physically capable of biting their own toungue.
- Venom cannot stay in the duct forever. It will need to be released or it will eventually have to be absorbed into the bloodstream.

Comment: Hi, Spirit. Can I ask what research you've done on your own on this? For instance: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0044523106000416 seems to answer your question. In the natural world, such creatures have mechanism (like folding fangs and specifically shaped tongues) to make biting their own tongue nearly impossible.

Comment: There are two problems with asking if something is plausible. (a) Per the [help/on-topic], our goal is to help you build an imaginary world. Therefore, *at best,* we'll help you build something that's believable. (b) You don't seem to have an actual problem to solve. We haven't worked out how to ask a "review my idea" question because that type of question breaks Stack Exchange's expectations for question structure. Do you have a specific problem to solve? Or are you simply asking if your idea is good? The former we can help you with. The latter... not so much. (\*Continued\*)

Comment: ... Bear in mind that people will happily suspend their disbelief for almost anything if the story is good. Therefore, while a creature not immune to its own poison seems dangerously irrational, it's by no means unbelievable - so long as your story makes sensible use out of the idea. Finally, though, (c) You're asking two questions: is it plausible and how can it be plausible are very different questions. Are you asking if it's a good idea, or for help with the physiology of the creature? The latter we can help you with, the former... not so much.

Comment: Is this question still active?

Comment: No, I've lost interest in it. Feel free to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

### What techniques can be used to keep magic weapon technology secret?

In a [previous question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/255721/why-could-the-militaristically-superior-dwarves-who-are-the-only-ones-with-magic) I had asked how I could ensure that they would not wish to go all imperial and stay isolationist despite the military might granted by them and an answer I really liked and plan to use is that others could steal the weapons and take the advantage. However, I don't know much about how they could try to limit the spread of that information to other countries because then they could lose the advantage regardless.

I don't need a way for the knowledge to be completely hidden but I would like some advice about what techniques or methods they could use to hide it like how some real world nations managed to keep trade secrets that could still be applied to magic technology.

One constraint with this question is that it is impossible to learn without weapons or a mentor as the weapons are made with a divine language forged into it that was gifted to the dwarves by the deity that created them. As an additional note he language has no effect when inscribed on anything else and may or may not have a spoken form. (I plan on actually making the whole language later after I finish a different language for that universe.)

> Does this version look better?

Comment: (a) Throw in a link to the previous question (e.g., \[In a previous question\]\(http:...\)) (b) Can a magical weapon be examined to "reverse engineer" the magic? Or must the process be stolen like a recipe from the manufacturer? (c) Keeping a perfect secret isn't impossible, but it's whomping hard. What, then, do you mean by "indefinitely?" (d) We've had similar questions like this, but they often suffer because you're not asking for help solving a worldbuilding problem. Rather, you're asking for help developing a story plot. (\*Continued\*)

Comment: ... From that perspective, you could (1) ask that answers be restricted to non-story solutions (e.g., the god won't allow the language to be used by anyone but dwarves) or (2) you could ask for help developing the nature of magic use for the dwarves (what's the magic system and how could it be crafted to make it ethnically keyed?). It's a skill to learn to separate the story from the world rules. I think this Q can be made to work, we just need to focus on rules vs. plot.

Comment: I find questions in absolutes to be not great. For the cases where an absolute is just unrealistic. Could dwarves completely control all information and no other outsider be able to glean it? Yes. But it'd be extremely hard and would basically mean no dwarf ever interacts with anybody else. If they do, sooner or later some information would leak out. However, dwarves can still maintain hold over the technology while others know some stuff about it. Dwarves can *limit* what others know and how useful it is. That's a lot more natural development that doesn't require author fiat.

Comment: Thus a lot more realistic scenario would be that other groups may be able to replicate some of what the dwarves can do. But in limited capacity - less quality, drastically less quantity (e.g., 1 magic sword for every 100 a dwarf can create), excessive cost, etc. And dwarves can keep their secrets so that nobody can really come close to rival them. Even if other magic weapons do exist in the world. Makes for way better setting, too with more potential stories to tell and other consequences where a world is not in absolutes. I'd recommend thinking about changing your world thus your question.

Comment: I think I'll probably just lax like like what @VLAZ suggested since I don't think itd work well for my world for it to be hard wired to be ethnically keyed, but in response to b.), since later I'll make an actual language (I'll refer to it as a conlang) it could be reverse engineered but it would require either trial and error or some way of learning the language from the weapons like a Rosetta stone. Currently I'm working on making a different language that's used among the gods, but later I'll move onto the magic weapon one.

Comment: And also I can definitely see how this is kinda more of a story question, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Oh and by indefinitely I hadn't quite meant literally but as of when the story would start it would have to have be at least past living memory of the dwarves when they had received the language without it yet being common.

Comment: A non-story based question can focus on what tools and techniques would be involved to keep the technology of magic weapons secret. Acknowledging it doesn't need to be completely sealed knowledge but what factors would limit the information that propagated outside to be as useful. This can have answers that point out how real-world trade secrets are kept. And how knowledge and skills were historically held by a given group.

Comment: Sorry, but what parts would I have to tweak to remove the story based part of it? You don't need to tell me exactly what to write (I'm aware this is a learning process) , I'm just not used to this sort of thing Edit: Wait I think I know what you mean now, I'll tweak this later this weekend when I have more time since I'll have to leave to go camping in a couple hours before returning on sunday

Comment: By the way real quick, I edited it to have a hyperlink and clarified on indefinitely, I'll try revamping the whole question later this weekend

Comment: @VLAZ Does this look better?

Comment: bump to show this isn't abandoned

Comment: So the weapon must be a specifically made weapon, the magic imbued by a specific person, and the magic can only be learned via a mentor? Does this boil down to "how do I protect the individuals who know the secret?" Please keep in mind that per the [help/on-topic], we help build worlds (rules independent of all stories) but don't help write stories. Specifically, we don't help you with choices made by individuals or groups. Thus, the question must be seeking a *systemic* answer. Is, e.g. "build a secret city and guard it to within an inch of its life" the type of answer you're looking for?

Comment: @JBH It's not a specific person per se, ideally it would be a whole field of work to create magic weapons and commonplace only WITHIN the kingdom (practically just a city state though), now that I'm reading this rephrasing though I'm seeing how it might cross the line into story building since it is technically just that nations decisions