# Where would asking for tip and tricks on worldbuilding go?

Tags: discussion

I think the question is pretty self-explanatory, so where can I ask more general world-building questions, such as style or general how to build a world kind of questions?

Comment: Never assume your question is self-explanatory. Examples of the kinds of quesitons you want to ask would help. Reviewing our [List of Worldbuilding Resources](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/143606/40609) would also help. Disappointingly, we don't appear to accept questions tagged [tag:worldbuilding-process] anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You can on this site

There's a [worldbuilding-process](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tags/worldbuilding-process/info) tag, which is specifically for questions about the overall process of worldbuilding, rather than on a specific point of one's specific world.

### However!

**Post your question in the [sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9981/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) before posting this question on main.** I really mean it. As you should be able to see on the [newest worldbuilding process questions](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/worldbuilding-process), this is rarely seen, and people often misunderstand what it actually means.

If it's not to ensure that your question is indeed self-explanatory<sup>1</sup>, it's to make your question stronger in order to break people's habits. When people are faced against the unusual, they will show more resistance than usual. So it's best your question has as little cracks as possible before it meets the big main site.

---

<sup>1 : Which is not a given. The "meta"-ness of such questions make them quite vulnerable to [lacking focus, details and opinion-based closures](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions).</sup>