# The Sandbox can use your help!

Tags: support, sandbox

I have great appreciation for the people who regularly help in [the Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9981/40609). I'd especially like to thank @Tortliena, @Sphennings and @VLAZ for helping so much.

But the Sandbox could use more help. Several questions have languished waiting for more input and one has only had input from me over the course of a month. The perspective of more people is incredibly valuable. This not only helps users perfect their questions, but it gives them insight into how to better use this Stack without questions being under threat of closure.

Please consider regularly donating time to help in [the Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9981/40609).

Also, please consider clicking the *Follow* link at the bottom of the Sandbox question. This will notify you when new answers (user questions to be considered) are posted.

Thank you!

Comment: Someone down voted a request for help in the Sandbox? Who would disagree with a service that helps users learn how to ask questions here?

Comment: I've never visited the sandbox before, but it looks very useful! I shall make it a habit to go there and help out!

Comment: Especially since I'm on a quite big leave. I can't even remember the last time I logged in o_x...

Comment: "*If it works like the old favorites star did, you'll be notified when new questions appear in the Sandbox.*" That was never true back from the old "Favourites" through "Bookmarks" to the newest incarnation "Saves". You'll not get notifications. If you *do* favourite/bookmark/save you would see updates in your profile, though. However, if you click the "Follow" button/link at the bottom of the question, you will get notifications for new answers being posted.

Comment: Thanks, @VLAZ! That makes a lot more sense. I've updated the post to say that.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some incentives to check the sandbox so you are actually interested to take a seat!

### Why do I want to check the sandbox's questions?

- It's as quick and easy as reviewing questions. I do it when I see the sandbox post being raised on the top of the page+@user comments, but yes, you can use notifications, too.
- You have much less troubles of people complaining their question is actually fit for the site. If they're sandboxing, they're willing to learn, .
- You'll feel less sad to give a downvote, because it happens you don't there<sup>1</sup>.
- By and through the above, I feel like the mood is better than on a soon-to-be closed question : It's a training ground, not the "actual exam".
- You can review your way of reviewing questions by comparing how you review questions vs how other reviewers review questions when it's finally posted on main. In simpler words, you get to know better what makes you unique in the community.
- You also fine-tune your boundaries of what should/shouldn't be accepted here because you get to have several close-looking questions as edits goes on.
- And you improve how effectively you guide people, which is kinda one of the top-tier communication skill you can get.

---

<sup>1 : Even though sometimes, some people don't remember the sandbox rules and still downvote/upvote :'(. Let's say it's just a misclick .</sup>