# Please take a moment to clear outdated comments from the Sandbox

Tags: discussion, sandbox

My sincere thanks to everyone who participates in the [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9981/40609)! We've built up a growing list of deleted posts (very normal!) and they could use a bit of maintenance to keep the web page from becoming cumbersome in browsers.

Please take a moment to visit the [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9981/40609) and perform a quick search for your user name. If you find comments in deleted or soon-to-be-deleted posts, please delete them. That really helps to keep the page manageable.

And if you haven't had the chance to help a new user (or, not that infrequently, an experienced user) in the [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9981/40609), please do so! It helps people learn how to use our Stack and lowers the number of closed questions.

Thank you!

Comment: I did my bit for king and country!